# Vue JS click event not firing up

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm developing app where I have a dynamic `.ddlist` for each `.box`.

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>MY LIST</h2>

  <div class="box">
    <input v-on:focus="showDDList" v-on:blur="showDDList" type="text" value="" placeholder="hello list">
    <ul class="ddlist">
      <li @click.prevent="myalert()" v-for="item in hello"><a href="">{{item.text}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

 <div class="box">
    <input v-on:focus="showDDList" v-on:blur="showDDList" type="text" value="" placeholder="there list">
    <ul class="ddlist">
      <li @click.prevent="myalert()" v-for="item in there"><a href="">{{item.text}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

What I want to achieve is when user focus on `input`, very next `.ddlist` should be visible. Here is Javascript part :

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    hello: [
      { text: "hello 1" },
      { text: "hello 2" },
      { text: "hello 3" },
      { text: "hello 4" }
    ],
    there: [
      { text: "there 1" },
      { text: "there 2" },
      { text: "there 3" },
      { text: "there 4" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    showDDList: function(e) {
            e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
        },
    myalert: function() {
            alert("Hello world");
        },

  }
})
```

My code is working fine until here and `.ddlist` does show up on focusing on `input`

What Next I want to do is When a user clicks on `.ddlist` child `a`, It should fire @click event binded to it.

There is a problem. Now when user clicks on `a` nothing shows up.
What I notice is because I'm toggling with css `display:block/none` of `.ddlist`, @click event is not firing up.

Here is the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6y9mwh3u/

May be you can throw some light on achieving my result with alternative ?

Comment: The problem is your blur event, when user click outside the input, the class active is removed, try to remove blur event

Comment: If you want to remove focus, you can remove the class `active ` from your `ddlist ` when other input element is focused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mousedown` event listener instead in order to execute `myalert` before `showDDList` since `blur` was preventing `click` from being called.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    hello: [
      { text: "hello 1" },
      { text: "hello 2" },
      { text: "hello 3" },
      { text: "hello 4" }
    ],
    there: [
      { text: "there 1" },
      { text: "there 2" },
      { text: "there 3" },
      { text: "there 4" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   showDDList: function(e) {
   e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
  },
    myalert: function() {
   alert("Hello world");
  },
    
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px #ddd solid;
}
.ddlist {
  display: none;
  margin-top : 10px;
}
.ddlist.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>MY LIST</h2>
  
  <div class="box">
    <input v-on:focus="showDDList" v-on:blur="showDDList" type="text" value="" placeholder="hello list">
    <ul class="ddlist">
      <li @mousedown.prevent="myalert" v-for="item in hello"><a href="">{{item.text}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 
 <div class="box">
    <input v-on:focus="showDDList" v-on:blur="showDDList" type="text" value="" placeholder="there list">
    <ul class="ddlist">
      <li @mousedown.prevent="myalert" v-for="item in there"><a href="">{{item.text}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
```